# Notepad++ search and add information, remove unwanted part

Tags: notepad++, regex

Using Notepad++ I have the following text:

```
[url=https://test.net/abcdef/]123456.mp4 - 510.03 MB[/url]
```

I want it to become:

```
https://test.net/abcdef/
```

"abcdef, 123456.mp4 and later part" are always changing.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am voting down this question since this is already 3rd question of the same author on the same topic where no effort is shown to learn and try and show what was attempted to do before asking here. For the author: please read help on [ask]. This time I am adding the answer to help you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what: `\[url=([^\]]+)\].*`

Replace with: `\1`

Search mode: `(•) Regular Expression  [ ] . matches newline`

*For the next time, please first study [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) first and in the question show what you tried so far, otherwise it may get closed without answering, since this site is not a code writing service.*